# Updating Application tile using TileUpdateManager

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using Windows 8 release preview and C#(VS 2012),I'm using below code to update Application tile.

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);

XmlDocument TileXML = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideImage);                

XmlNodeList imageAttribute = TileXML.GetElementsByTagName("image");
((XmlElement)imageAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Tile.png");
((XmlElement)imageAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "red graphic");

TileNotification notify = new TileNotification(TileXML);
notify.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10);

TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notify);
```

But my Application Tile is not updating, I don't know what I'm missing and where  I'm doing wrong, please help me.

I got the answer, its about adding Extension file "NotificationExtensions.winmd" as my reference and also i have couple of questions

1. When i run above code by setting my target device as "Local
   Machine" it works but when i set it to "Simulator" it doesn't, Can
   any one explains me please why.
2. We have expiration time for tiles by using below line
   `notify.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10);`
   what i have to do if want the live tile to be running continuously,

   Please let me know if have any links or study material
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work without the notification delay?  does your Tile.png conform to the size restrictions < 200KB and < 1024x1024? and not to state the obvious, but your start screen tile is wide - right?

Comment: Does it work if you don't set ExpirationTime?

Comment: just popped this code into the tile and badge sample on dev.windows.com and it works.  Only difference is that I don't have your image (I used the redWide.png) in the sample, so perhaps there's an image size issue? or the image as referenced isn't in your app package?

Comment: Thank you Guys, i got it my image size is <200KB and < 1024x1024, i haven't added extension file "NotificationExtensions.winmd" as my reference. i did that and i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Guys,i got the answer, my image size is <200KB and < 1024x1024, mistake i did is i haven't added extension file "NotificationExtensions.winmd" as my reference. i did that and i got it.